# Iterable's ConstraintValidator return invalid values

Tags: java, validation

Is there any way to return (within the `Set<ConstraintViolation>`) the list of invalid values in case of applying
`ConstraintValidator<SomeAnnotation, Iterable<String>>` on collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can mix the concepts mentioned in these posts:

- [Custom javax list of string pattern validator](https://spacanowski.github.io/java/validation/jsr-303/2015/10/23/string-list-pattern-validator/)
- [Creating custom constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html), Example 6.4

You just need to define your own syntax how the validated object gets referred in order to identify within your input collection:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

    // Your validation code

    if ( !isValid ) {
        constraintContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        constraintContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
                "{org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter03." +
                "constraintvalidatorcontext.CheckCase.message}"
        )
        .addConstraintViolation();
    }
    return isValid;
}
```